# Why the wide character woes?

Tags: c, ncurses

In attempting some work with ncurses I've come to the point where I need to use wide characters, for box drawing, but also for other stuff, and I'm in a situation where per-tile control is useful.

However, when attempting to use the following code, I get into trouble:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED

#include <locale.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ESC 27

int main() {
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

  initscr();
  keypad(initscr(),1);
  curs_set(9);
  nonl();

  cchar_t special;
  setcchar(&special, L"æ", 0, COLOR_PAIR(0), NULL);

  cchar_t speshul;
  setcchar(&speshul, L"朝", 0, COLOR_PAIR(0), NULL);

  int c=0;
  do {
    clear();

    mvadd_wch(3,6, &special);
    mvadd_wch(4,6,&speshul);

    refresh();

  } while ((ESC!=(c=getch())));

  endwin();
}
```

**Edit:**

Having updated the code to use `setcchar`; the output is disheartening:

```
?
```

A single question mark where `special` should be, and nothing where `speshul` should be.

Neither character shows up as expected.

Where is the problem, and how can I fix it?

**Edit:** Some extra info in response to Petesh:

The expected result is the printing of the character "æ", and underneath it, 朝. I'm using Terminal.app on Mac OS X; and I'm compiling it Xcode.

Comment: I believe the way you're *supposed* to create `cchar_t`s is with the [`setcchar(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcurses/setcchar.html) function (not to mention the fact that the actual implementation of `cchar_t` is implementation-defined).

Comment: @jwodder: Updating the code to use `setcchar` has not in fact improved things. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The devil, as it turns out, is in the details.

It turns out my problem was the call to locale:

```
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
```

It should read:

```
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8") // or similar
```

Setting that fixes the issue, and the characters now display correctly.

Answer (score 5):

There are many other "woes" in your code, and some might be related to your wide character issues:

---

```
initscr();
keypad(initscr(),1);
```

Avoid calling `initscr()` twice for no reason. Either store the result of the first call in a `WINDOW` pointer, or simply use the built-in `stdscr`. Also avoid numeric constants for `bool` values, prefer the named constants `TRUE` and `FALSE`. The semantics are quite different.

So use:

```
WINDOW *screen = initscr();
keypad(screen, TRUE);
```

or

```
initscr();
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
```

---

```
curs_set(9);
```

`9` is not a valid argument for `curs_set()`. From the manual: *"The  curs_set  routine  sets  the cursor state to invisible, normal, or very visible for **visibility** equal to **0**, **1**, or **2** respectively"*

---

```
setcchar(&special, L"æ", 0, COLOR_PAIR(0), NULL);
```

The 4th argument of `setcchar()` is `short color_pair`. It expects a color pair *number*, not its *attribute mask* (which is supposed to be applied to a `chtype`). This is poorly documented, I agree. Using `COLOR_PAIR()` only works for pair 0. For an arbitrary pair, say pair `4`, use:

```
setcchar(&special, L"æ", WA_NORMAL, 4, NULL);
```

Also use `WA_NORMAL` instead of `0`. Do not rely on the constants values, use the named ones!

---

```
while ((ESC!=(c=getch())))
```

You should also test for an `ERR` return. Don't assume `c` will always contains a valid character code:

```
while ((c=getch()) != ERR && c != ESC)
```

Also, if you really want to use `ESC` as the character to break the loop, you should read about `ESCDELAY`. By default it takes an annoying whole second between an ESC is pressed by user and that key is made available to your program. The reason, in simple terms, is ESC is also used to initiate an *escape sequence*, so curses must wait to see if an ESC is followed by other control characters before deciding it was an isolated key press. So you can't avoid a delay, but you can reduce it to a less perceivable time, say 100ms. This must be set *before initializing curses!*

```
setenv("ESCDELAY", 100, FALSE);
```

And careful when using `getch()` in a wide-character world. For a simple "loop until ESC" this is fine, but replace it with `get_wch()` when you want to actually parse user input.

---

Finally, you should not need to set locale to `"en_US.UTF-8"`, as this will override the user's locale. What if your terminal is set to a character encoding other than `UTF-8`, or your language is not `en_US`? Just set your program to use whatever locale is set in the *user environment*:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

This is very different from not setting locale at all, as by default C, the language, assumes the locale is `C`, ie, 7-bit ASCII characters only. And curses honors that.

Comment: This is the real answer to this question, especially regarding the locale issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the following questions:

1. What is the expected result (because it works on my system)
2. What is the terminal you're using - i.e. OS (windows/etc), application
3. Are you editing the file in the window that you're compiling it in
4. You may want to try --encoding=UTF-8 at the compile line if your environment does not interpret it correctly, and assuming that the file is in the UTF-8 mode. If you're using windows you may be able to just use UCS-16 as the encoding.