# NCurses Unicode in stdscr but not in WINDOW

Tags: c++, unicode, ncurses

I am trying to print Unicode in NCurses.

And I cannot figure out why does the following code work for `stdscr` but the screen remains empty for `wnd`.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

short color;

void print_wide(WINDOW* win, int x, int y, const std::wstring& str)
{
    cchar_t printBuffer[60];
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    {
        setcchar(&printBuffer[i], &str[i], A_NORMAL, color, NULL);
    }
    mvwadd_wchnstr(win, y, x, printBuffer, str.length());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ch;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();          // Start curses mode

    WINDOW* wnd = newwin(33, 24, 0, 0);

    init_pair(color, COLOR_CYAN, COLOR_BLACK);
    cbreak();           // Line buffering disabled, Pass on everything to me

    std::wstring str1 = L"Right arrow: \u2192\n";
    std::wstring str2 = L"Left arrow: \u2190\n";

    print_wide(stdscr, 0, 0, str1);
    print_wide(stdscr, 0, 1, str2);

    refresh();

    ch = getch();
    endwin();           // End curses mode
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks, Miha

Comment: This answers your question: [Does refresh() need to be called at least once, when using windows in ncurses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462603/does-refresh-need-to-be-called-at-least-once-when-using-windows-in-ncurses).  There are several duplicates.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check this answer and try to make it work in my actual (and a bit more complicated) program.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: Changing the `refresh` and `getch` to their window specific versions did not help much. It turned out the main issues was this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29004722/3989524 . Specifically the part where `setcchar` expects a raw _color pair number_, and not the _attribute mask_ provided by the `COLOR_PAIR` macro.